# Segmentation fault by realloc, while creating dynamic generic array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I tried to implement a dynamic generic array. However, when I tested my code, the result I got was "segmentation fault". I know that this error happens by realloc in a function ArrayListResize, but why?

Here is my implementation of a few methods:

```c
typedef struct ArrayList {
  void** arr;
  size_t allocated, len;
} ArrayList;

int ArrayListInit(ArrayList *list) {
  list = (ArrayList *)malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
  if (list == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, FAILED_ALLOCATION_MSG);
    return -1;
  }
  list->allocated = 0;
  list->len = 0;
  list->arr = (void **)NULL;
  return 0;
}

int ArrayListAppend(ArrayList *list, void *item) {
  if (item == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, INVALID_ARG_MSG);
    return -1;
  }
  if (ArrayListResize(list, list->len + 1) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  list->arr[list->len] = item;
  return 0;
}

int ArrayListResize(ArrayList *list, size_t len) {
  void **arr;
  size_t allocated = list->allocated, new_allocated;
  if (allocated >= len && len >= (allocated >> 1)) {
    assert(list->arr != NULL || len == 0);
    list->len = len;
    return 0;
  }
  if (len == 0)
    new_allocated = 0;
  else
    new_allocated = len + (len >> 3) + (len < 9 ? 3 : 6);
  arr = (void**)realloc(list->arr, sizeof(void *) * new_allocated); // Here I get the segmentation fault
  if (arr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, FAILED_REALLOCATION_MSG);
    return -1;
  }
  list->arr = arr;
  list->allocated = new_allocated;
  list->len = len;
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the test code:

```c
int* GenerateIntPointer(int n) {
  int* ptr_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *ptr_int = n;
  return ptr_int;
}

int main() {
  ArrayList list;
  ArrayListInit(&list);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ArrayListAppend(&list, (void*)GenerateIntPointer((int)i));
  }
  ArrayListDelete(&list, free);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A significant problem is that your `ArrayListInit` function is not actually initializing the `list` object you have declared on the stack in your `main` function! You have the line

```cpp
  ArrayList list;
```

which sets aside memory for an `ArrayList` object on the stack. However, since it's a struct, then for efficiency & smaller code size purposes, the values are likely *not* initialized. Actually, since you've tagged this with [c](/questions/tagged/c), then there are no even implicit constructors and C compilers won't initialize it. Even with a CPP compiler on a .c file, or with a .cpp file since there is no explicit constructor, no initialization will very likely occur even then.

Your code is then passing a pointer to this object in the line

```c
  ArrayListInit(&list);
```

where the `ArrayListInit` code reassigns its parameter, i.e., also called `list`, to a new memory location, i.e., with

```c
  list = (ArrayList *)malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
  if (list == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, FAILED_ALLOCATION_MSG);
    return -1;
  }
```

Thus, the remaining initialization lines there, i.e.,

```c
  list->allocated = 0;
  list->len = 0;
  list->arr = (void **)NULL;
```

update the newly allocated object, not the original `list` object in `main`. Thus, in `ArrayListResize`, the values passed to `realloc` are *not* valid, just whatever the stack bytes had initially, thus causing the segmentation fault.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove the lines in `ArrayListInit` which change the passed in `list` pointer value to a new memory location. Alternatively, especially if you will only be using one `ArrayList` object, you can get rid of the `ArrayListInit` method and just initialize the object values directly, e.g., as suggested in [Neil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749455/segmentation-fault-by-realloc-while-creating-dynamic-generic-array#comment137069661_77749569), i.e.,

> You definitely want to initialize it; for example, `ArrayList list = {0}` or `ArrayList list = {0,0,0}` (C90).

In either case, you may also need to make an appropriate corresponding change to your `ArrayListDelete` function.

Alternatively, if you wish to have and use a dynamically allocated `ArrayList` object, then you would need to make several other changes. First, in `main`, have your declaration line be something like

```c
ArrayList* list;
```

Then change your `ArrayListInit` function to have a parameter of `ArrayList** list`. In the rest of that function, change `list` to be `*list`. In the `main` function, change the `ArrayListAppend` call to pass in just `list`. Finally, you will need to make the corresponding changes in your `ArrayListDelete` function.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for the suggestion. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for your additional feedback. My recollection is that C doesn't initialize stack variables. However, it's been so many years since I last programmed in C (I've mostly been doing C++ and C# programming instead), I wasn't sure if perhaps there might be some exceptions among the C compilers, especially more recent ones.

Comment: It's kind of a feature of the language :). This is exactly what's happening; good catch. If it were an `ArrayList *const list`, it would have caught this in compiling.